# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fabSize': attr 'rippleColor'

Tags: android, xml, git

I have started the "Firebase Essentials For Android" - Udacity course,have downloaded the code on Git and GitHub,
and am trying to run the app on my tablet.

I am using the eclipse environment, as that is what I am used to, and am getting some error messages.
I have tried looking up solutions on SO and updating the Android properties and the Build path, but all is to no avail. My Android SDK is up to date.

My error messages are:

> \res\values\styles.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fabSize'.
>   \res\values\styles.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'rippleColor'.
>   \res\values-v21\styles.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fabSize'.
>   \res\values-v21\styles.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'rippleColor'.

Would you guide me please? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use resources that are not available in your SDK or on the API you're targeting.

Raise your compileSDKVersion to 21 or above, target API 21 or above, and use appcompat-v7 library instead of 4.

For example, build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```